# How to extend moduleManager in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to extend standard Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager, is it possible?
For example I want to load modules list from database and I want to add some methods for working with modules.

If I set factory to serviceManager:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'moduleManager' => 'Path/To/My/ModuleManager',
    ),
),
```

There is error "A service by the name or alias "modulemanager" already exists and cannot be overridden, please use an alternate name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module manager in Zend Framework 2 is created via a service factory class. `ModuleManager` is mapping to `Zend\Mvc\Service\ModuleManagerFactory`. I advice you to have a look on this `ModuleManagerFactory` and see what object are injected in the module manager on `createService()`.

If you want to extend and use your own module manager you must create a class that extends ModuleManager but also create a service manager factory that overwrites the Zend\Mvc\Service\ModuleManagerFactory. You are on the right way with the following code but it is important to put this code in the `/config/application.config.php` file because this is the config file that Zend\Mvc uses to create the main services.

```
// config/application.config.php
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'ModuleManager' => 'Path/To/My/ModuleManagerFactory', // <-- Path to MM factory
    ),
),
```

The link below will give you good information about what default services are run with \Zend\Mvc and how and where this is happening:

https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.services.html

Hope this helps, feedback will be appreciated :)

Stoyan